# How to convert dataset object to List<string> in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list

I am returning a result set of rows from database and I want to assign these values on UI for HTML controls.

I am fetching the data into DataSet from DB.

For ex my data looks like following:

```
ID  EmpId    Question    Comments

1    2        abcdefgh   comments1
2    6        xyhgjkjh   comments2
3    6        kjhkjhjk   comments3
4    6        uyyiuyuui  comments4
5    3        erteyeyuy  comments5
6    6        qapooioip  comments6
```

Based on the input(EmpId) I fetch data.For ex EmpId = 6, I want to display the above data on UI using HTML fields like following:

Q1. xyhgjkjh

comments2

Q2. kjhkjhjk

comments3

Q3.uyyiuyuui

comments4

Q4.qapooioip

comments6

I just want to display in a HTML Label by looping through my result set from database.

I am creating properties like following:

```
Public class MyClass
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public int EmpId{get;set;}
   public String Question{get;set;}
   public String Comments{get;set;}
}
```

I want to use the above class and set the result set values to the properties and loop through it and assign to HTML controls on UI.

How do i convert the dataset and set it to MyClass obj properties and assign it to the HTML controls in VB.NET.

Do i need to have List for Question property?

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am really having a hard time trying to understand your question. What is your actual problem? Converting the `DataSet` to your class representation? Displaying the data structured in `MyClass` objects on a webpage? Filtering the data? All of it? What web technology are you using? WebForms? MVC? Razor?

Comment: Its a asp.net web form. I have a dataset now and I want to loop the dataset and assign each value to the my class object(may be List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your class:

```
' I'm going to assume that the class properties are in the same order as the dataset and that there is only one table in the dataset.

Dim TheClassInstance as MyClass ' Create an instance of the class
Dim MyClassList as List(Of TheClassInstance)
Dim MyDataRow as DataRow
For Each MyDataRow in TheDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
     TheClassInstance = New MyClass 
     TheClassInstance.Id = MyDataRow(0)
     TheClassInstance.EmpId = MyDataRow(1)
     TheClassInstance.Question = MyDataRow(2)
     TheClassInstance.Comments = MyDataRow(3)
     MyClassList.Add(TheClassInstance)
     ' Everytime you loop you're adding an instance of the class to the list
Next
```

To access each instance of the class you can loop through using a for each loop or a loop using a variable as an index that you use to get the data in the list.  Using a for each loop:

```
Dim MyClassInstance as new MyClass
For Each MyClassInstance in MyClassList 
    ' You can set the text property of labels and textbox controls to the data
    Textbox_Comments.text = MyClassInstance.Comments
    ' ... etc
Next
```

**Edited to account for multible question per parent:**

Change your class:

```
Public class MyClass

   Public Property Id as Integer
   Public Property EmpId as Integer
   Public Property Question as List(of String)
   Public Property Comments as String

End Class
```

I assume that there is a parent table with EmplId's and a child table of Questions for each EmplID:

```
Dim TheClassInstance as MyClass ' Create an instance of the class
Dim MyDataRow as DataRow
Dim MyDataRow2 as DataRow ' For clarity
For Each MyDataRow IN ParentDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
     TheClassInstance = New MyClass 
     TheClassInstance.Id = MyDataRow(0)
     TheClassInstance.EmpId = MyDataRow(1)
     TheClassInstance.Comments = MyDataRow(3)
     Dim MySecondDataSet as Dataset = GetQuestions(MyDataRow(1) ' Get questions for EmplId
     For Each MyDataRow2 in MySecondDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
         ' It's assumed that the question is the only column in the table
         TheClassInstance.Questions.Add(MyDataRow2(0))
     Next
Next
```

**When all the questions are in one row in the table:**

```
Dim TheClassInstance as MyClass ' Create an instance of the class
Dim MyDataRow as DataRow
For Each MyDataRow IN ParentDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
     TheClassInstance = New MyClass 
     TheClassInstance.Id = MyDataRow(0)
     TheClassInstance.EmpId = MyDataRow(1)
     TheClassInstance.Comments = MyDataRow(3)
     ' I assume that the questions start in column 4
     ' Add each question in the row, I assume 4 questions in order
     TheClassInstance.Questions.Add(MyDataRow(4))
     TheClassInstance.Questions.Add(MyDataRow(5))
     TheClassInstance.Questions.Add(MyDataRow(6))
     TheClassInstance.Questions.Add(MyDataRow(7))
Next
```

Comment: The instantiation should be at the beginning of the loop, not at the end, or you will get a `NullReferenceException` in the first iteration.

Comment: there is a instantiation outside the loop before the loop so it doesn't matter ...

Comment: Ok, now there is. I am still of the opinion that you should not instantiate more objects than you need (the last object will never be used and just uses up memory).

Comment: Ok ... just getting him started ... it's gone as soon as he leaves the procedure or code block anyway ... but there is an argument for manually cleaning up the garbage ... lol ...

Comment: No, it is not gone as soon as he leaves the procedure. This is VB, not C.

Comment: @PrescottChartier Perfect answer. This is what I am looking at. Thanks much for the help.

Comment: @PrescottChartier How do i do this if i want to have only one EmpId and multiple Question for one object of MyClass.

Comment: @PrescottChartier its like i want to make Question property as List<String>

Comment: Then make the MyClass Question propery a list of strings, for example: `Public Property Question as list(of string)`.  For each question in your database for a particular (student?) record add to the list, for example: `MyClassInstance.Question.Add(question)` ...

Comment: @PrescottChartier I made Public Property Question as list(of string). But I'm not getting how to loop from the dataset.Can you please explain by adding(editing) to the answer i accepted

Comment: @PrescottChartier I checked your edited answer. But I have all the columns in one table and i fetch them to dataset using one storedprocedure. So its a one result set. 'Select Questions from myTable where EmpId = 6'. My result dataset has questions as well. So there is no need of another 'GetQuestion' method. How can we do for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to create a method for converting `DataRow` to your class `MyClass`

```
Public Function ToMyClass(row As DataRow)
    Return New MyClass With
    {
        .Id = row.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
        .EmpId = row.Field(Of Integer)("EmpID"),
        .Question = row.Field(Of String)("Question"),
        .Comments = row.Field(Of String)("Comments"),
    }
End Function
```

Generic method `DataRow.Field(Of T)` will cast column value to expected type, which provide some type safety provided by compiler - you need set `Option Strict` to `On` for this.

Then you will be able to create list of your classes in "one line"

```
Dim data As DataTable = dataset.Tables(0)
Dim questions As List(Of MyClass) = 
    data.AsEnumerable().Select(AddressOf ToMyClass).ToList()
```